# AfNetworking 2.0 posting issue

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

i have recently wanted to use Afnetworking in my ios application. the same page responds me by using `ASIHTTPREQUEST`. but it simply does not with the AFNetworking. Here is my effort.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"user[height]": @"10",
                             @"user[weight]": @"255"};
    [manager POST:@"http://localhost:8888/TestingPost/post.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Now i have tried many options like adding serialization to different xml / json / html. but of no use.

On PHP page i am not doing something fancy just printing out whatever is posted on the page. still here it is.

```
<?php
// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL

header('Content-type: application/JSON');



print_r($_POST[]);
/*
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$password = $_POST['password'];
*/

//echo( "hurray");

?>
```

Can you please shed some light on it. i want to switch from `ASIhttprequest` to newest and more supported.

Here is the result for the request

```
Networking_example[1777:41979] Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x7f9feae16d60 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9fedb029a0> { URL: http://localhost:8888/TestingPost/post.php } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Thu, 16 Oct 2014 18:08:08 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.10";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8888/TestingPost/post.php, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}
```

Comment: BTW, your PHP a specifies a JSON header (and I think that's supposed to be `application/json`), but not returning JSON. Either change it to return JSON, or change that header (e.g. `application/text`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP is using `$_POST`, that means that you are ok using the default `requestSerializer` of `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` (i.e. an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request).

But your JSON is not generation JSON response, so you have to change the `responseSerializer` to `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`.

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

And your PHP page is reporting a 500 error. That is an "Internal Server Error", for which [the status code definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

That suggests a PHP error. Perhaps you intended:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

---

Generally, when interacting with web service, it's better to generate JSON response, e.g.

```
echo(json_encode($_POST));
```

Obviously, if you generate JSON response, you might also want to use the default `[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]` setting, rather than changing it to `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`.

Comment: but the same page works for ASIhttpRequest. if there is an issue in web page it should not work on that library as well. i will give try this and update accordingly

Comment: BTW, you can observe your ASI request using [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and repeat with AFNetworking. You'll be able to determine what's different in the two requests that way.